# draw multiple texts on button for android,inner-shadow

Tags: android, draw

I need a way to draw multiple texts for a button in android..
I would like to simply just extend the default android button with the possibility to have an aditional text that should be overlapped by another text to create sort of a very "intense" inner-shadow effect.

The idea as mentioned is to simply extend the default button and override the onDraw-function and then draw a new text at the same position as the "default-text" for the button.. the problem is that I have no idea about how Im supposed to get the location of the "default-text" for the button..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use multiple views to create this effect.  I wrote a blog post awhile back about using `EmbossMaskFilter` to apply this effect to a `TextView`.  `Button` is just a glorified `TextView`, so you can use the same approach to modify its display text through a simple subclass:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2012/04/textview-inner-shadows/

One thing to keep in mind is that this filter is not yet supported by hardware acceleration, so you may need to draw this view on a software layer if the rest of your app takes advantage of acceleration on newer devices (if you don't know whether or not it is, by default it probably is).